# The real rows of csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, ubuntu

I have a csv file which has so many rows and I want to get the number of rows in my python program.
When I use `wc -l` or vim the file and set-number to count number of rows, I got 7125393.[the number of rows when I run `wc -l`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzsMo.png)

But when I use pandas to parse the csv and use `.size` to get the number of the rows, It returns 6842536. Then I use `csv` which is python's built-in package to parse csv and use for loop to count the number of rows, it also returns 6842536.

I don't know why the difference would be occurs between python and ubuntu when i count the rows number of csv file.

Comment: any blank lines in ur csv? possibly pandas skipped the blank lines. seems weird though

Comment: I don't sure, the file is too large.But my csv file can't be so many blank lines, I think it's not caused by blank line. I think the possible reason that given by @Valdi_Bo is right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of plain `wc -l` call, start from:

```
cat your_input.csv | sed '/^\s*$/d' | wc -l
```

This way you will not count lines which are either empty or contain
only "white" chars (or maybe `sed '/^$/d'` to skip only empty lines).

Remember that `read_csv` has `skip_blank_lines` parameter,
which by default is `True`.

## Edit

Another possibility is that the source file can contain lines
terminated with `\`.
Such cases are treated by *read_csv* as "continuation of this line is
in the next line", so these 2 (or more) lines contain data for
a **single** row in the resulting DataFrame.

The above rule pertains also to the **title** row.

I tried an input file with  the following content:

```
a,b,\
c
aa1,12,30
aa2,13,\
32

aa3,14,34
aa4,15,36
aa5,16,38
```

so that:

- row *aa2,13,* has continuation in the next line,
- the next row is empty (I tried also a version that it contains only
  spaces).

Such a file read with *read_csv* gives a DataFrame with just **5** rows,
but `wc -l` will count **9** lines here.
As *skip_blank_lines* parameter has its default value (*False*),
both empty lines and lines containing only spaces are also skipped.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply and I try the command which you gave with my csv but it returned 7125348.

 Maybe the forloop in python will lose a part of data?